# Wait for JavaFX Application Thread to finish handling events?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, javafx, concurrency

Lots of questions on here are asking about how to pause the JavaFX Application thread for a background thread, but I want the opposite!

I'm trying to test how long it takes for a series of key inputs to be fully handled. I am using the [Automaton](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton) testing library for JavaFX, and editor.type(key) generates a keypress event that gets processed by the application. Here is one of many attempts:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

editor.type(AGUtils.LEFT_ARROW);
editor.type(AGUtils.LEFT_ARROW);
editor.type(AGUtils.RIGHT_ARROW);
editor.type(AGUtils.RIGHT_ARROW);

FutureTask<Callable> t = new FutureTask<>(...);
Platform.runLater(t);

while (!t.isDone()) { } // wait for the FutureTask to be called

long end = System.nanoTime();
```

However, it seems the FX Application Thread might be handling the FutureTask before it handles the rest of the keypress events.

TLDR: I want to precisely measure when the JavaFX Application Thread has finished handling the four keypress events I generate.

How can I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569

Answer (score 2):

Use  `ExecutorService` and wait until your threads are done. Store a timestamp of when you started the service and then compare the difference between the two times to get your answer.

A simple example on how to use the `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
while(...) {
  taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());
}
taskExecutor.shutdown();
try {
  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Mind if I ask about the approach you've mentioned? I am able to generate inputs that get handled by FX EventHandlers, but I don't exactly know how those events are represented in JavaFX's internals before the Application thread calls the relevant handle() methods in my program. I had thought using Platform.runLater() would insert an event into the queue in successive order (after the keypresses), but I was wrong. How would I use an ExecutorService in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: I added a basic example on how to use the service. I would need more time to write a more elaborate one.

Comment: Instead of writing an entirely new code example this answer  might help you out further if my answer isn't satisfactory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394428/javafx-version-of-executorservice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pour over both of them carefully!